# Consulta POST a una página .ASPX desde Excel VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, post, https

he creado la siguiente macro, en Excel VBA, para realizar una consulta POST.

```
Sub ConsultaPOST()
Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim reqURL As String
Dim reqBody As String

    reqURL = "https://www.sbs.gob.pe/app/spp/empleadores/comisiones_spp/Paginas/comision_prima.aspx"
    req.Open "POST", reqURL, False
    req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    
    reqBody = "cboPeriodo=2016-07&btnConsultar=Buscar+Datos"
    req.send reqBody
    
    Debug.Print req.responseText

End Sub
```

La función de la macro es consultar información de dicha página (URL) seleccionando un periodo específico, para ello en el cuerpo de la consulta considero: cboPeriodo=2016-07 y btnConsultar=Buscar+Datos, éste ultimo es un botón de enviar. Sin embargo obtengo como respuesta la información del periodo actual, que aparece por defecto en dicha URL. Para esta consulta utilizo un objeto de la librería Microsoft XML V. 6.0 (MSXML2.XMLHTTP60) sin embargo he utilizado WinHttp V. 5.1 con el mismo resultado. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: en el código parece que no estas enviando el reqbody en el send.
req.send reqBody

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. No lo había considerado en la pregunta pero si lo hago. Ya lo corregí.